# How to fetch single item out of long string?

Tags: python

I have a very string as output of function as follows:

```
tmp = <"last seen":1568,"reviews [{"id":15869,"author":"abnbvg","changes":........>
```

How will I fetch the `"id":15869` out of it?

Answer (score 0):

The string content looks like JSON, so either use the json module or use a regular expression to extract the specific string you need.

Comment: Can you elaborate more how can i use regular expression to extract the specific string?

Answer (score 0):

The data looks like a JSON string. Use:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

tmp = '"last seen":1568,"reviews":[{"id":15869,"author":"abnbvg"}]'
data = json.loads('{{{}}}'.format(tmp))

>>> print data
{u'reviews': [{u'id': 15869, u'author': u'abnbvg'}], u'last seen': 1568}
>>> print data['reviews'][0]['id']
15869
```

Note that I wrapped the string in `{` and `}` to make a dictionary. You might not have to do that if the actual JSON string is already encapsulated with braces.

Comment: i have python 2.5.will it support jason?

Comment: OK. the `simplejson` module is compatible with 2.5, you can get it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is the only thing you need from the string and it will always be something like `{"id":15869,"author":"abnbvg"...`, then you can go with sinple string split instead of json conversion.

```
tmp = '"last seen":1568,"reviews" : [{"id":15869,"author":"abnbvg","changes":........'
tmp1 = tmp.split('"id":', 1)[1]
id = tmp1.split(",", 1)[0]
```

Please note that `tmp1` line may raise IndexError in case there is no `"id"` key found in the string. You can use -1 instead of 1 to side step. But in this way, you can report that `"id"` is not found.

```
try:
    tmp1 = tmp.split('"id":', 1)[1]
    id = tmp1.split(",", 1)[0]
except IndexError:
    print "id key is not present in the json"
    id = None
```

If you do really need more variables from the json string, please go with mhawke's solution of converting the json to dictionary and getting the value. You can use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
from ast import literal_eval
tmp = '"last seen":1568,"reviews" : [{"id":15869,"author":"abnbvg","changes":........'
tmp_dict = literal_eval("""{%s}"""%(tmp))
print tmp_dict["reviews"][0]["id"]
```

In the second case, if you need to collect all the `"id"` keys in the list, this will help:

```
id_list =[]
for id_dict in tmp_dict["reviews"]:
    id_list.append(id_dict["id"])
print id_list
```